# Missing libopencv_ts missing under arm-linux

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, ros, catkin

I have a ros node that I am trying to compile. I keep getting and `Error 2`.

Looking into the output I found:

```
 ** No rule to make target /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.8, 
 needed by <my node>.
```

Is it correct to assume that this is the cause of the error, which results in an incomplete build.

I then did a cache search and found `libopencv-ts`, when I wanted to install it I saw that it would remove all my ros and tegra packages. Since I do not want to reinstall my entire system, could somebody help if I can get the `libopencv_ts` another way, e.g. a special package or install that package from source?

Or do I have to go the dreaded way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (I would recommend doing dd to have a backup if needed)

I then uninstalled the rospackage for opencv (`vision_opencv` and `image_pipeline`). I then downloaded from source (github) `image_common`, `vision_opencv` and `image_pipeline`, and chose the appropriate branch (depended on your ros installation).

I copied the cloned repositories into my `catkin_ws` and build first the packages with `catking_make --pkg <pkgName>`, (this removes issues with other libopencv packages e.g. `libopencv_videostab.so`). After that then build everything with `catkin_make` and you should be good to go.